# What would be the best way to copy large file from local system to a pod in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a large file of around 350GB that need to be copied to the pod with PV, I have been trying to use kubectl cp but after all the tries I haven't been able to copy the whole file. Is there a better way to copy the file?

**Note: Kubernetes Cluster and Local System on which the files exist are on the same network in a cloud environment.**

The error I am getting:

```
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
```

Answer (score 2):

`...350GB that need to be copied to the pod with PV`

How about create a PV that *already* loaded with the 350GB data? In this case all your pod needs is just the PVC.

Updated: In case of Portworx, you refer an existing PV which previously dynamic created and **retained** by:

```
...
persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
portworxVolume
  volumeID: <existing volume id>
```

See the Portworx documentation [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/blob/master/staging/volumes/portworx/README.md#persistent-volumes).

Comment: constraint is that we are using a software-defined storage (Portworx) and pv and PVC are generated dynamically and I don't see a way to reference the pv or PVC anywhere on the node.

Comment: See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

By using PVC (**persistent volume claim**) you can copy the large number of volume data to your pods.

A persistent volume claim is a dedicated storage that kubernetes has carved out for your application pod, from the storage that was made available using the storage class. you can refer this [link](https://blog.mayadata.io/kubernetes-storage-basics-pv-pvc-and-storageclass) .

Comment: the constraint is that we are using a software-defined storage (Portworx) and PV and PVC are generated dynamically and I don't see a way to reference the PV or PVC anywhere on the node.

Comment: As per @gohm'c , If your using Portworx and if you referring an existing PV which previously created, by using this document you can do the required modifications. https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/blob/master/staging/volumes/portworx/README.md#persistent-volumes